# How to handle errors in saving image from camera?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an applicaiton which takes has a camera. After clicking the picture you can save the image in phone. I have seen several tutorials and written the code accordingly(I am new in Android studio). 
Yet I am getting syntax error where as others are not getting them. 
I have two activities. Below is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.none.www.dumpcam;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String currentImagePath = null;

    private ImageView mimageView;
    private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void captureImage(View view){

        Intent imageTakeIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(imageTakeIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
            File imageFile = null;
            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if(imageFile!=null){

            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context:this, authority:"com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile); //one error is shown here
            imageTakeIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(imageTakeIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }

        }

    }

    public void displayImage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayImage.class);
        intent.putExtra(name: "image_path", currentImagePath);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

        private file getImageFile() throws IOException{
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageName = "jpg_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, suffix ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }

}
```

Following is my DisplayImage.java:

```
package com.none.www.dumpcam;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DisplayImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.mimageView);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra( name: "image_path"));  //One error is shown here. 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Like I said I am writing the code from tutorials. There code is working fine.
I am getting the following syntax errors:

```
com/none/www/dumpcam/DisplayImage.java  
error: ')' expected 
error: ';' expected 
error: illegal start of expression  
error: ';' expected 
com/none/www/dumpcam/MainActivity.java  
error: ')' expected 
error: not a statement  
error: ';' expected 
error: not a statement  
error: ';' expected 
error: not a statement  
error: ';' expected 
error: not a statement  
error: not a statement  
error: ')' expected 
error: ';' expected
```

Comment: I am quite sure that `.getStringExtra( name: "image_path"));` (the `name:` in specific) is invalid Java Syntax. I would highly doubt the tutorial has the same code compiling.

Comment: I would assume you can safely remove all `something:` instances and just take the strings. The tutorial potentially put them in to highlight what the string stands for (iow the name of the parameter). I don't know why they would use this style though in all honesty over using a comment.

Comment: ahh yess that solved it. there was no need to write 'something' before strings